# generate backup file using date and time as filename

Tags: batch-file, mysql

How do I do this properly. I'm trying to name the sql file that is being produced by mysqldump into the current date and time. I've already some research in this site and found a code in here: [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi)

Tried to mixed it up with my current code and I came up with this one. The file is named into the current date and time but its only a 1kb file and does not produce a .sql file. 
It is supposed to be a 7 kb sql file.

```
@For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do @(set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
@For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do @(set mytime=%%a%%b)    

@echo mydate= %mydate%
@echo mytime= %mytime%

mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-table --create-options --password= onstor >c:\%mydate%_%mytime%.sql
```

**UPDATE**
I don't think there's a problem with the mysqldump command since it works well when I do it this way. The code below just uses the date as its filename.

```
@For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
    Set Month=%%A
    Set Day=%%B
    Set Year=%%C   
)    

@echo DAY = %Day%
@echo Month = %Month%
@echo Year = %Year%    

mysqldump -u root --add-drop-table --create-options --password= onstor >c:\%Day%-%Month%-%Year%.sql
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On Linux, simply put `$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S)` to show date and time in the file name, so it looks like:

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p <database> | bzip2 -c > <backup>$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.bz2
```

(This command also compresses the file using bzip2)

Comment: The question is windows-specific.

Comment: For linux :`$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S)` right BUT what for WINDOWS?

Answer (score 4):

I think the syntax of your mysqldump command is wrong;

```
mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-table --create-options --password= onstor
```

You use both `-p` and `--pasword=`, you should only use one option. And there is a space before the password.

Just try to run the mysqldump command on the commandline to see error messages. Alternatively add `2>&1` at the end of the command in the batchfile. Then you would also see error messages in the output file.

```
mysqldump -u root --add-drop-table --create-options --password=onstor >c:\%mydate%_%mytime%.sql 2>&1
```

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with the mysqldump command, please see my edit

Comment: @user225269: the mysqldump command is different in your second example. But anyway, can you show us what the 1kb file contains?

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to get this to work in crontab, in that case it's a bit different:

```
30 01 * * * /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=MySecretPass database_name | gzip >  /path/backup/`date "+\%d-\%m-\%y_\%H:\%M"`.gz
```

Comment: Path for the mysqldump will normally be /bin or /usr/bin

Comment: Yes David, that is correct, depend of the O.S., In my case i have AWS Lightsail with ubuntu